# Error trying to pull sender email address from microsoft outlook 2010 and comparing it to a string

Tags: c#, outlook-2010

The below code works 9 out of ten times, but in some cases I get the error of:
Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously. Try closing messages you have opened or removing attachments and images from unsent messages you are composing.

I checked the email it's trying to pull and they are all just normal messages. There isn't any meetings or anything like that. I even cleaned some of the emails out of that sort.

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

        NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
        MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

        var mail = myInbox.Items;

        foreach (object items in mail)
        {
            var item = items as MailItem;
            if (item != null)
            {

            if (!senderEmail.Equals(String.Empty) && senderName.Equals(String.Empty) && emailSubject.Equals(String.Empty))
            {
               try
                    {
                        if (((MailItem)item).SenderEmailAddress.ToLower().Contains(senderEmail.ToLower()))
                        {
                            if (count <= 40)
                            {
                                if (((MailItem)item).SenderEmailAddress.Contains(""))
                                {
                                    var senderEmailAddress = ((MailItem)item).SenderEmailAddress.Remove(((MailItem)item).SenderEmailAddress.IndexOf(""), 32);
                                    resultsGrid.Rows.Add(count, ((MailItem)item).Subject, ((MailItem)item).SenderName, senderEmailAddress, ((MailItem)item).CreationTime.ToString());
                                    resultsGrid.AutoResizeColumns();
                                }
                                else if (((MailItem)item).SenderEmailAddress.Contains(""))
                                {
                                    var senderEmailAddress = ((MailItem)item).SenderEmailAddress.Remove(((MailItem)item).SenderEmailAddress.IndexOf(""), 75);
                                    resultsGrid.Rows.Add(count, ((MailItem)item).Subject, ((MailItem)item).SenderName, senderEmailAddress, ((MailItem)item).CreationTime.ToString());
                                    resultsGrid.AutoResizeColumns();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    resultsGrid.Rows.Add(count, ((MailItem)item).Subject, ((MailItem)item).SenderName, ((MailItem)item).SenderEmailAddress, ((MailItem)item).CreationTime.ToString());
                                    resultsGrid.AutoResizeColumns();
                                }

                                count++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                resultsGrid.Rows.Add(String.Empty, "Total items in      Mailbox: " + myInbox.Items.Count, String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (COMException e)
                    {
                        resultsGrid.Rows.Add(e.Message);
                        resultsGrid.AutoResizeColumns();
                        break;
                    }
                    continue;
                }
     }
```

Comment: Silly question but is the code just automating the Outlook running on your desktop? (I've done something similar in Powershell.) If so, do you just have too many Outlook windows open (as a desktop user, not through your code) when it fails?

Comment: This is just automating the Outlook running on my desktop, but I have special reasons to why I want to do it this way.

I do not have too many windows open...idk what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Sure, just remember that the code uses exactly the same application instance as you do via the GUI. If you have "random" errors, it might be because you were doing something specific in Outlook via the GUI at the same time.

Comment: When I run this code, I have outlook open and I am not doing anything in it. I do not have any windows open besides the main window. During it running, I get this error.

Comment: In that case, I don't know, sorry.

Comment: I also get this error, and neither GC.collect() or System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mailItem); resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GC.Collect(), I was able to force the program to clean up the previous objects/calls to Outlook.

I know it's not the best idea to call GC.Collect(), but I believe it fits the criteria given here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2004/11/29/271829.aspx

The problem, I believe, is that I am generating many requests to open up many different emails and garbage collection usually happens at random it isnt happening fast enough so by the time I reach my limit garbage collection needs to happen. The problem is that it isn't happening before I do so I need to call GC.Collect() every so often to ensure I am resetting those open objects I have.